# Declaration Expected

Tags: vb.net

Good day all. Please advise me
Why I got an error message "Declaration Expected" when put the cursor on cmd variable. What Should I do?! .. the code appears below:

```
Imports System.Data.Sqlclient
Imports System.Configuration

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits Page
    Private Shared Connectionstr As String ="DataSource=localhost;initialCatalog=Orders;Integrated Security=true"
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(Connectionstr)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
   cmd.CommandText="SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers"
End Class
```

Comment: What should you do? What are you _trying to do_?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use the variable command outside a Property, Function, or Method. At the very least, try wrapping your command in a method (Sub) which performs the desired action with the data:

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits Page

```
Private Sub DoSomethingWithCustomers()
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(Connectionstr)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers"

    conn.Open()
    Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    ' Do something with the data returned . . .
    ' ...
    ' Now Cleanup:
    conn.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    conn.Dispose()
End Sub
```

The above can be improved by wrapping your data access objects in Using blocks, which handle proper disposal of unmanaged resources for you:

```
Private Sub DoSomethingBetterWithCustomers()
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(Connectionstr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            ' Do something with the data returned
            ' . . . 
            dr.Close()
        End Using ' Using Block takes carre of Disposing SqlCommand
    End Using ' Using Block takes care of Closing and Disposing Connection
End Sub
```

Beyond that, it is difficult to know what, precisely, you are trying to do with your code, so the two examples above are really, really basic and general.